# How to fixed overlapping notes in a kendo chart?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-chart

I have several series with notes overlapping like this: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/oVen

I tried to change the position of the notes but It doesn't always work
If there any way to separate them automatically or manually? Please help

Answer (score -1):

Try below link which alters the position according to the point.value:
Please refer the function against the position of the notes in series:

```
series: [{
                .........
                .........
                .........
                  notes: {
                      label: {
                          position: "outside",
                          format: "n2",
                          background: "rgb(35, 47, 87)",
                          color: "white",
                      },
                        position: function(point) {
                        var result = "bottom";
                        if (point.value % 2 === 0 || point.value < 5) {
                            result = "top";
                        }

                        return result;
                    }
               }

            }],
```

[Updated Code Link](http://dojo.telerik.com/@NitinMall/aBuQ/2)